# Efficient Way Of Writing Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

User Has Three Text Boxes Name,Number,Email.Here User May enter details in three text boxes or may be two or one Based On the Entered data There is a table `'tblSample'`. '`tblSample'` has `Name,Number,Email,Adress,Contact Number`.

For example, If user enters only Name as ' Sai Bharath' I should display all the details from the table `'tblSample' Where Name='Sai Bharath'`.Like that user may enter two text boxes or three text boxes What is the best and easiest way to get this?

Comment: Build Sql command in your app client .

Answer (score 0):

Use below code is easiest way to get result :

```
SELECT * FROM #tblSample
WHERE ( @name <> '' AND Name = @Name ) OR
  ( @number <> 0 AND Number = @number ) OR
  ( @email <> '' AND Email= @email)
```

Comment: It will not support NULL = NULL, you can test on my sample data, it will return only one row though we have two rows ? you should handle null condition anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `COALESCE()` function in SQL server. You don't need to use `IF- Else` or `CASE` in your statements. Here is how you can use the `COALESCE` function.

```
SELECT * FROM tblSample where Name= COALESCE(NULLIF(@Name, ''), Name) and Address= COALESCE(NULLIF(@Address, ''), Address) and Email= COALESCE(NULLIF(@Email, ''), Email) and [ContactNumber=
COALESCE(NULLIF(@ContactNumber, ''), ContactNumber)
```

The `COALESCE` function in SQL returns the first non-NULL expression among its arguments. Here for example if the @Name is equal to null the function will return Name which will lead to Name=Name in the where statement which is like 1=1 meaning the condition will always be true.

Comment: "Name=Name .. which is like 1=1" except Name is NULL.

Comment: It will not support NULL = NULL, you can test on my sample data, it will return only one row though we have two rows ? you should handle null condition anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We can check in the condition if only variable/parameter has value otherwise we can return true by checking null but if no any variable has value it will return all records. We can avoid this by adding condition with mandatory variable if we have:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblSample(NAME VARCHAR(50),Number INT,Email VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #tblSample VALUES 
('Tom', 001122, 'tom@test.com'),
('Usy', 001123, 'usy@test.com'),
('Nuse', 001124, 'nuse@test.com'),
('Tom', NULL, 'tom@test.com')

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) = 'Tom', @number INT, @email VARCHAR(50)

SELECT *
FROM #tblSample
WHERE 1 = 1
AND (@name IS NULL OR NAME = @name)
AND (@number IS NULL OR number = @number)
AND (@email IS NULL OR email = @email)
```

Output:

```
NAME    Number  Email
Tom     1122    tom@test.com
Tom     NULL    tom@test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about textboxes, I suppose you have some kind of service layer that calls your procedure from the data layer. One way is to use Entity Framework and LINQ2SQL to generate exactly the minimum query needed for your filtering scenario.

One possible way to do this:

```
// no need to track the entities, since you are just reading the data
var query = DataContext.Set<Person>().AsNoTracking();

// query can be built step by step and will be as simple as possible
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    query = query.Where(p => p.Name == name);
if (number.HasValue) 
    query = query.Where(p => p.Number = number);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
    query = query.Where(p => p.email = email);

// you can also TOP your record set, so that you do not bring a very large number of rows
query = query.Take(100);

// actually run the query and get the data
var listOfPersons = query.ToList();
```

LINQ2SQL is very powerful and may allow partial match (Contains), if needed.

The stored procedure solution may lead to [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/). However, for large sets of persons, the appropriate indexes are still required to avoid table scans.